# Parent folder script FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, path, file-not-found

My Python app contains a subfolder called Tests which I use to run unit tests. All of my files are in the parent folder, which I will call App. The Tests folder contains, say, a test.py file. The App folder contains an app.py file and a file.txt text file.

In my test.py file, I can make my imports like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("PATH_TO_PARENT_DIR")
```

Say my app.py file contains the following:

```
class Stuff():
    def do_stuff():
        with open("file.txt") as f:
            pass
```

Now if I run test.py, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file.txt'
```

How can I fix this? Many thanks!

Comment: give full path of your text file ...eg : C//user/full_path//file.txt

Comment: @sachindubey Why doesn't the relative path work ?

Comment: Sorry I'm a little tired. I just understood the comment. What do you mean by "give the full path"? Do I have to add it to my path manually, similarly to adding the path to the parent folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file is located in the same folder as your script:

```
import os
parent_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
class Stuff():
    def do_stuff():
        with open(os.path.join(parent_dir, "file.txt")) as f:
            pass
```

Explanation:

`__file__` is the path to your script

`os.path.dirname` get's the directory in which your script sits

`os.path.abspath` makes that path absolute instead of relative (just in case relative paths mess your script up, it's good practice)

Then all we need to do is combine your `parent_dir` with the file, we do that using `os.path.join`.

Read the docs on `os.path` methods here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

A more explicit version of this code can be written like this, if that helps:

```
import os
script_path = __file__
parent_dir = os.path.dirname(script_path)
parent_dir_absolute = os.path.abspath(parent_dir)
path_to_txt = os.path.join(parent_dir_absolute, 'file.txt')
```

Comment: Thanks Ofer, I used the following solution found somewhere else: `MAIN_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())))`

Answer (score 1):

The `open` function looks for the file in the *same folder as the script* that calls the `open` function. So, your `test.py` looks in the tests folder, not the app folder. You need to add the full path to the file.

```
open('app_folder' + 'text.txt')
```

or move the `test.py` file in the same folder as `text.txt`

Comment: Thank you. Could you give me a way to do this without explicitly giving the parent folder's path? Using sys functions, I mean. I need this to work in production too and it doesn't sound like a great idea to start defining explicit paths.

Comment: You could use `os.path.join(path, file)` instead, but the fact remains that you somehow *have to* define the folder the files are in. If it is the parent folder, you could use `..` as the path, but the best way would be to define that path in a configuration file, and create a function that wraps `open`